# Marginal distributions of a random vector

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have the random vector $(X,Y)$ with density function $8x^{2}y$ for $0 < x < 1$, $0 < y < \sqrt{x}$ I am trying to find the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$. For $X$ this seems to be simply the integral $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}8x^{2}y = 4x^{3}$, which is also the given solution, and follows the general formula I've gotten, where you find marginal distributions of a variable by integrating the joint PDF of all other variables over their supports. However, this seems to fail in the case of $Y$, where I try the integral $\int_{0}^{1}8x^{2}y = \frac{8y}{3}$, conflicting with the given answer of $\frac{8y}{3}(1-y^{6})$. What am I misunderstanding here? This seems painfully simple, and I have never had issues finding a marginal distribution like this before.

Comment: If you pick a particular $y$, are all $x$ values allowed? (Drawing the allowed region helps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prescribe $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ by $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto1$
if $x\in\left(0,1\right)\wedge y\in\left(0,\sqrt{x}\right)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto 0$ otherwise. Then
the PDF for $X$ and $Y$ are respectively:

$$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\int g\left(x,y\right)8x^{2}ydy$$ and: $$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int g\left(x,y\right)8x^{2}ydx$$

For a fixed $y\in\left(0,1\right)$ we find $f_{Y}\left(y\right)=8y\int_{y^{2}}^{1}x^{2}dx=\frac{8}{3}y\left(1-y^{6}\right)$
and for a fixed $y\notin\left(0,1\right)$ we find $f_{Y}\left(y\right)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture. The joint density function "lives" over the part $D$ of the unit square that is below the half-parabola $y=\sqrt{x}$.

To find the density function of $y$, we have to "integrate out" $x$.  The function $8x^2y$ is the joint density only on $D$, so we have to confine attention to $D$.

Note that at the beginning of $D$ we have $y=\sqrt{x}$, that is, $x=y^2$. And at the end we have $y=1$.